# Add Segmented Control In Empty Space of Numerical Keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uikeyboard

My topic is a little bit difficult to explain so I have attached a picture.

As can be seen, there is an empty space in the bottom left of the keyboard. I was wondering if there were any way to use this space by, as the title states, adding a segmented control.

Thankyou

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but I'd flip the order of the "Done" and "Cancel" buttons in your UIToolbar. Cancel on the left and Done on the right is a common pattern.

Comment: thank you, I have changed them.

Comment: Put the control in your `inputAccessoryView`.

Comment: @rmaddy, sorry I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Put the control on the same view you use for the Done and Cancel buttons.

Comment: @rmaddy you mean in the toolbar?

Comment: Yes, if that's what you used.

Comment: the question was to create the segmented control in the empty space of the keyboard, not the toolbar.

Comment: Since you can't do what you are asking, I'm suggesting an alternative solution.